# Broadcast events on AngularJS service to keep controller(s) updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’ve got a registered *service*, which provides common getXYZ() methods to retrieve service’s data. Any *controller* can access the service and its methods via dependency. However the service data are changing **independently of controller**, and I need to keep controllers updated.

I found effective to use `$rootScope` in the service and broadcast various events to controllers in the root scope via `$rootScope.$broadcast()`, and handle necessary events via `$scope.$on()` in a controller, then update the model via $scope.$apply().

Is it a good approach how to keep the controller updated or it is an anti-pattern in AngularJS?

Comment: Do the events that change the model in the service come from outside the AngularJS framework?

Comment: I this case yes, the events come from outside the AngularJS framework, thus no cycles are expected.

Comment: In that case, I recommend using `$rootScope.$apply()` inside the service instead of `$scope.$apply()` inside each controller.

Comment: Pushing events from a service with $broadcast is not an anti-pattern, but consider using a more modern technology like [rxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/). It will make the migration path to Angular 2+ easier.

Comment: If the $scope.on is triggered you don't need the $apply as you are already in the digest loop.

Comment: BTW: This is a good point whether the event is came out of NG or not. If the origin event come from some other NG service, e.g. `$http`, then it is not needed to call `$scope.$apply()`  from the controller event handler to avoid errors such as `$apply / $digest already in progress`. Is it a good practice?